# Automatically login to wireless?

Tags: wireless-networking, automation, authentication, automatic-logon, wifi-configuration

Annoyingly enough when connecting to my wireless network at university, it opens up my browser and requires me to enter in my username and password.

Is there a way to skip this process?

(I am on Windows 8 x64; but can move to Ubuntu 13.04 x64 once my graphic drivers are fixed)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using LastPass. It is a browser extension that can save passwords. If you turn off log off security for LastPass, you can set the wifi portal address to be AutoLogin. That should automate the WiFi login process going forward.

Comment: The only hitch, I don't know if LastPass caches the password datatabase on your machine or not. If not, it won't be able to enter the password to connect to the wi-fi until... it connects to the wi-fi

Comment: Lastpass do store their database locally --> https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=425

Answer (score 1):

The closest you're going to be able to get is if your browser will save the credentials. Most campus networks use a *captive portal* to authenticate students and guests. Once you're authenticated, there's a timeout value associated to your session. After the timeout value is exceeded, or perhaps if you connect to another network, the wireless controllers will force you to re-authenticate.

Comment: Yeah, but I was thinking that I would be able to script that handshake…

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a script that logs in to the wifi without a ui, in a text based browser such as lynx, for example.

Then you'll need to trigger the script on network connection or login, for example.

100% possible on Linux, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/menasheh/66a7b824e53d0ca75e94d95a844f8400).

Should be possible on Windows as well. [Here](https://peromsik.com/blog/how-to-set-up-automatic-wifi-captive-portal-login/)'s my guide for Windows, people have had varying degrees of success.